# Find which elements have ::after pseudo-element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of labels and want to scrap only some of them.

```
<div>
  <label class="search-reusables__value-label">
    ::before
    <p class="display-flex">...</p>
  </label>

  <label class="search-reusables__value-label">
    ::before
    <p class="display-flex">...</p>
    ::after
  </label>

  <label class="search-reusables__value-label">
    ::before
    <p class="display-flex">...</p>
  </label>

  <label class="search-reusables__value-label">
    ::before
    <p class="display-flex">...</p>
    ::after
  </label>
</div>
```

I'm only interested in the labels that have the `::after` pseudo-element.

One label I want to get for example:

```
<label class="search-reusables__value-label">
  ::before
  <p class="display-flex">...</p>
  ::after
</label>
```

And one I'm not interested in:

```
<label class="search-reusables__value-label">
  ::before
  <p class="display-flex">...</p>
</label>
```

This question seems close to what I want to do:
[How locate the pseudo-element ::before using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python), but I couldn't get it to work.

I tried for example

```
script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('label.search-reusables__value-label'),':after').getPropertyValue('content')"
print(driver.execute_script(script).strip())
```

But the result I get is   (a blank space).

Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689722/how-locate-the-pseudo-element-before-using-selenium-python) you mentioned, there is a text inside the `::after` pseudo element and the goal there is to extract that text.
While in your case there is no text inside the `after` pseudo element and you want to locate the parent elements themselves based on existence of pseudo `::after` elements inside them.
This can be done with the following JavaScript:

```py
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('label.search-reusables__value-label'), ':after'")
```

While the similar question here is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116426/how-do-i-find-parents-of-pseudo-element-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But I don't know how to make this work in the example I gave. I executed `driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('label.search-reusables__value-label'), ':after'")` but it returns nothing? How can I get the 2 labels with the code you provided?

Comment: Using `driver.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll('label.search-reusables__value-label')")` I can get all the labels as webelements, but whenever I add the `':after'` part it returns `:after` and not the webelements. Any idea?

Comment: Currently I have no solution for that, I'm sorry. Maybe I will try doin that later. In case you find solution yourself - please let me know, that is interesting.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't find anything else for the moment unfortunately.

Comment: Me too, also currently I have no time for that, I'm sorry. But in case you finally find a solution - and I believe you will do - please let me know, it's interesting.

Comment: I found another solution (using `is_selected` with a webelement) which works in my use case. But I don't have the time either to look more into this, so if anyone has a solution, I will gladly accept it.